# linux gnome online video play issue

Tags: video, youtube, archlinux, gnome, pacman

I'm using arch linux with gnome.

All the online video always show buffering but my network seems available(at least fast enough to browse stackoverflow).Actually when I get to a particular spot of the video,the frame can be shown
successfully while it is still buffering.btw,youtube's video preview(mouse hovering) is ok,i can see that.

[youtube screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwS8O.png)
It was fine before I turn my desktop environment form xfce4 to gnome.

here is my **/var/log/pacman.log**

```
[2023-02-04T23:23:22+0800] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Rns xfce4 xfce4-goodies'
[2023-02-04T23:23:32+0800] [ALPM] transaction started
[2023-02-04T23:23:32+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-taskmanager (1.5.5-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:32+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-screenshooter (1.10.3-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:32+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin (0.4.5-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed libkeybinder3 (0.3.2-4)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed ristretto (0.12.4-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfwm4-themes (4.10.0-4)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfwm4 (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfdesktop (4.18.1-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-terminal (1.0.4-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-settings (4.18.1-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed gnome-themes-extra (3.28+r6+g45b1d457-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed elementary-icon-theme (7.2.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-session (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xorg-xinit (1.4.2-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xorg-iceauth (1.0.9-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed polkit-gnome (0.105-9)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-power-manager (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-notifyd (0.7.3-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-panel (4.18.1-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed libwnck3 (43.0-3)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed libxres (1.2.2-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfce4-appfinder (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed tumbler (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed thunar-volman (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed thunar (4.18.3-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed garcon (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed exo (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed libxfce4ui (4.18.1-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed xfconf (4.18.0-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] removed libxfce4util (4.18.1-1)
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] running '30-systemd-update.hook'...
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] running 'gio-querymodules.hook'...
[2023-02-04T23:23:33+0800] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2023-02-04T23:23:34+0800] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
```

but i don't think any of it involves the problem
ps:only this part involves removal,others are things like **pacman -Syu**

I've checked the Internet and turned off all the gnome extension,I also reinstalled ffmpeg,but obviously it's kind like online video thing。

Answer (score -1):

solved,refer to [a solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2035399#p2035399)!
comment out

```
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

in **/etc/pulse/default.pa**